# draw a/the conclusion that……

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

Templates for argumentative essays:

> (In light of this event,) I can safely draw **a/the** conclusion that
> __________________.
>
> Therefore, I can arrive at **a/the** conclusion that __________________.

Google Ngrams shows [“the" is used much more](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draw%20a%20conclusion%20that%2Cdraw%20the%20conclusion%20that%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20conclusion%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20the%20conclusion%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdraw%20a%20conclusion%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20the%20conclusion%20that%3B%2Cc0), but google books has [countless pages of "draw a conclusion that......"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22draw%20a%20conclusion%20that%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2012,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) Are they grammatically wrong?

In this kind of appositive clauses, I can't tell the difference. When is it better to use "a"?
Does it matter if this sentence summarizes a body paragraph or is a thesis statement?

Let me provide two examples:

> (In light of this event,) I can safely draw **a** conclusion that traveling alone is more flexible.
>
> Therefore, I can arrive at **the** conclusion that it is better travel alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite article *the* is for something specific, unique.

All your examples are talking about drawing *one* specific conclusion and detailing what it is, so you should use the definite article.

The only situation in which you might refer to "*a* conclusion" is if you are still considering multiple possibilities, for example:

> I have not yet drawn a conclusion.

Once a conclusion has been drawn, anything else you may have been considering is no longer valid - it is *the* conclusion.

Comment: I thought so, but google has countless pages of "draw a conclusion that......" Are they grammatically wrong?

Comment: @joy2020 You can have multiple conclusions from something. In such cases, it's correct to call each "a conclusion". "The conclusion" indicates a specific/important conclusion, which maybe is the only one you're interested in.

Comment: (After a quick look) - Some of them don't refer to a specific conclusion - _Draw a conclusion that is not justified_ - _Draw a conclusion that may be either true or false._ I find it odd to use the indefinite article when a specific conclusion is being referred to, though I wouldn't  go so far as to call it grammatically wrong.

Comment: @StuartF  Based on what you said, I assume you think this is okay: I have multiple conclusions from this experience; for instance, I draw a conclusion that we should not delay things.   (@kateBunting maybe this is a specific conclusion, but it's okay to use the indefinite article?)

Comment: @KateBunting  "There was a suggestion that Brown should be dropped from the team."   Maybe this is a specific suggestion, but it's okay to use the indefinite article, because it could imply there are several suggestions?

Comment: @StuartF I agree with what you are saying to a degree - we could say "each drew **a** different conclusion". But the very nature of a 'conclusion' is that it is the end of a matter. Any given individual cannot finally reach multiple conclusions.

Comment: I think "There was a suggestion that Brown should be dropped" works because it was one among several suggestions made by the assembled company. Compare "[Someone] made *the* suggestion that Brown should be dropped."